# how to call a function of class based tkinter Frame from another class based frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter application that has multiple class based frames and I would like to call a function which is in tkinter Frame from another frame/class.

For example, my frames are like this:

```
    
class_B(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            
        def Update_class_b():
        label = tk.Label(class_B, text=f"Welcome", font=LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        # wigdgets
        button = tk.Button(self, text="START_TRIP", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(D_file.D_class)
        #i am using this controller to navigate between those pages

        # packing/grid
        button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Now, I would like to call the function  `update_class_b` from another class base frame. How can I do that right now I am passing `class_B` in label widget while making it as you can see and directly calling it in `class_A`, but it is not working. Please if anyone could help me regarding this.
Also, I would like to call this `update_class_b` function from inside another class based frame like while pressing a button in `Class_A` this function should be triger

class A would be like

```
class class_A(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        def do_something_in_class_B():
            #this should trigger Update_class_b function in class_B

        button = tk.Button(self, text="DO SOMETHING IN CLASS B", command=do_something_in_class_B).pack()
```

controller class

```
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        


        for F in (file_A.Class_A,file_B.class_B):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(startPage.StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tkinterApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your frames stored in a dictionary in the controller frame:

```
func = controller.frames[class_B].update_class_b
button = tk.Button(self, text="START_TRIP", command=func)
button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```

We'd have to see a MCVE to give a specific answer.

Comment: i have added controller class please have a look

Comment: I see I assumed correctly. Not much else I can tell you without an [mcve].

Comment: where i have to put this code? I am not able to understand

Comment: You have not shown us enough of your code for us to know where you need to put this. You need to show a [mcve] when you ask software questions.

Comment: PLEASE have a look now i have edited the question with what i want in class a to happen